# Finding taylor expansion for $\tanh(x)$

Tags: hyperbolic-functions, bernoulli-numbers

I am a high school student and am trying to find the taylor expansion of $\tanh(x)$ in terms of a summation form. I have gotten this far, and am aware it might get complicated very quickly. If someone could aid in finishing it for me (or show a source (note I am still only a senior student so if you could not skip any steps).

I said:

$$\tanh(x) = c(1) + c(2)x + c(3)x^2 + c(4)x^3 + ... c(n)x^{n-1}$$

$$\tanh(x)\cosh(x) = \sinh(x)$$

$$(c(1) + c(2)x + c(3)x^2 + c(4)x^3 + ... )(1 + ((x^2)/2!) + ((x^4)/4!) + ... ) = x + ((x^3)/3!) + ((x^5)/5!) + \ldots$$

then from there, I got that,

$$\tanh(x) = c(1) + c(2)(x) + (c(3)+(c(1)/(2!))(x^2) + (c(4)+(c(2)/(4!))(x^3) + (c(5)+(c(1)/(4!)+c(3)/(2!))(x^4) + (c(6)+(c(2)/(4!)+c(4)/(2!))(x^5) + (c(7)+(c(1)/(6!)+c(3)/(4!)+(c(5)/(2!))(x^6) + ...$$

As is obvious there are a multitude of patterns, after each power of two progression of $x$, there is an extra way of attaining that power of $x$. (eg. in the first 2 terms of the expansion, there is only 1 way to attain that power of $x$, in the next 2 terms, there are 2 ways to attain that power of $x$, increasing by 1 every 2 terms.

I could name countless other obvious patterns though I don't think that is very useful.

I am thinking that pascal's triangle might come in the explanation somewhere however not sure where.

Also I am not sure what the Bernoulli series are which I think is important in order to find the summation expression, if someone could either find a summation expression which doesn't use Bernoulli's numbers or is willing to explain this to me, that would very generous of you.

Please keep it at high school level (and it doesn't matter if the final summation isn't simplified, as long as it is understandable), if there is something that needs to be introduced (such as the Bernoulli numbers), I will learn it (maybe provide a source which explains this to me in detail, would be nice).

Thank you so much, I will be extremely grateful, you have no idea how happy I will be once I finally get it, I just can't stop thinking about it!

Comment: Your answer involves Bernoulli numbers.  If you have never heard of them, then this problem is probably too advanced for you.

Comment: do you have a source which can explain this to me, or can you explain it step by step?

Comment: I have already had a look at them, and know there is a polynomial etc..

Comment: @GEdgar The Bernoulli numbers are advanced, but that doesn't mean OP can't grasp them if he is willing to learn.

Comment: Yes I am willing to put a lot of effort behind this.

Comment: Here is a web page to read... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number

Comment: Yes but I want to know the mechanism from how to get the Bernoulli numbers from above

Comment: I $\LaTeX$ified your math to make the question more readable.  Hope I got it right.  Try $\LaTeX$--you'll like it!  Nice question, by the way, ***plus one!!!*** Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Direct computation from the definition of Taylor series for $f(x)=\tanh x$ about $x=0$ gives
$$
\tanh x=\color{blue}{x-{x^3\over 3}+{2x^5\over 15}-{17x^7\over 315}+\cdots}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty {2^{2n}(2^{2n}-1)B_{2n}x^{2n-1}\over (2n)!}, \quad |x|<{\pi\over 2},
$$
where $B_{2n}$ refers to the $2n$th Bernoulli number which can be defined in a variety of ways. I suggest reading about them [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number) and choosing whichever definition is most accessible to you in order to generate them.

The the first expression in blue not sufficient, especially for a high school level? Or are you requiring a general formulation for the $n$th term as on the right above? Because if so, you will be forced to deal with the Bernoulli numbers.

Comment: Can you show how you got to that summation formula, stating it isn't very helpful. From the sequence that I provided how does it show the summation that you stated (prove using maths)? Thanks anyways for your efforts!

Comment: Show that it is true or show how someone originally thought to go from the blue to the black? If the former, simply evaluate the pattern in the summation for various values of $n$ and see that they match then proceed formally by induction. As for the latter? Probably through staring at it for quite a while and either defining $B_n$ to accomplish the missing part of the task and/or importing prior knowledge about the Bernoulli numbers. No one said going form the blue to the black was trivial. Many times finding a general pattern for the $n$ coefficient is highly nontrivial.

Comment: However, your question was "find the Taylor series for $\tanh x$ about $x=0$". There it is (in blue) by direct computation to as many terms as you like.

Comment: Ok. In that case, can you simply expand the known summation (which contains the Bernoulli), and find the summation without using the Bernoulli numbers, (I'm guessing this is done by substituting the expansion for the Bernoulli's numbers into that summation).

Comment: Yes you can....

Comment: How would you do that tho?